# python - Extract attributes having setter properties in an object

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, getter-setter

I have an object. Using `__dict__`, I can list down all the attributes of the object. Using `__dir__`, I can list down all the methods and attributes of the object. Is there a way to list down the attributes having setter properties declared in the class whose instance the object is.

Comment: what do you mean by "the setter functions" ?

Comment: You can do `filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, property), map(lambda y: getattr(type(obj), y), dir(type(obj))))`.

Comment: I meant the setter property definition. The function with @property decorator

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```py
isinstance(getattr(type(object), 'attribute'), property)
```

Thanks to @a_guest and OP Rahul Nahata's own prior edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To check if an object is a `property`, use `isinstance(value, property)`.

To list all the attributes and methods of a class, use: `vars(MyClass)`.

Combine everything and get:

```py
all_property_names = [name for name, value in vars(MyClass).items() if isinstance(value, property)]
```

---

With the following class,

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 1

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    def notproperty(self):
        return self.x
```

you would get:

```
# all_property_names
['x']
```